# Syntax Error while Parsing XML

Tags: php, rss

I am trying to get the rss feeds of a site as XML and trying to display it but I am geting Syntax error, My whole code is as:

```
<?php 
   header('Content-type: text/xml');
   $feeds = file_get_contents('http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories');
   $xml = simplexml_load_string($feeds);
   foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
      print $item->title;   
   }
?>
```

The error I get is

**XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: localhost/rssfeed.php**

Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What output do you get if you comment out the `header()`?

Comment: I get the titles correct but I want to see the whole xml structure, How can I view it?

Comment: code please to understand your problem?

Comment: because you only print the title

Comment: I want to print it as xml document

Comment: @MarieLuise - what kind of object does `simplexml_load_string` return? Does that object have an iterator built in?

Comment: @andrewsi when I print $xml it display nothing

Comment: @MarieLuise - I suggest you read the documentation for the function you're using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: @MarieLuise I answered your question regarding the syntax error. Now you're asking me how to add image, description, how to get all item data to be saved in HTML file. It has nothing to do with the original question, and you're just asking me to do it for you when I helped you with your original error. I suggest you start from what I told you and try it yourself. If you have later issues, ask a new question, I will happily answer it. In the mean time I'll just delete my question since it doesn't make any sense in regards to what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your getting XML Parsing Error because your not outputting proper XML, by setting the header content type the browser is expecting valid xml.

Try this:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/xml');

//Load your feed (input)
$feed = file_get_contents('http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories');
$feed_xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);

//Create a new SimpleXMLElement object (for output)
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><news/>');

//Loop each item from $feed_xml->channel->item
foreach ($feed_xml->channel->item as $item) {
    //Create a story node for each item
    $node = $xml->addChild('story');
    //Loop each items & add it to the node if its a title or description
    foreach($item as $key=>$value){
        if($key == 'title'){$node->addChild($key, $value);}
        if($key == 'description'){$node->addChild($key, $value);}
    }
}

//Use dom document to format the output nicly, not required
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());

echo $dom->saveXML();
/**Output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<news>
  <story>
    <title>Ryan says Obama undercuts welfare reform law</title>
    <description>Republican vice presidential candidate Paul Ryan says President Barack Obama wants to ease work requirements for welfare recipients even though that claim has been largely debunked by independent fact checkers.</description>
  </story>
  <story>
    <title>Greenpeace activists storm Russian oil rig</title>
    <description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://news.yahoo.com/greenpeace-activists-storm-russian-oil-rig-063813773.html"&gt;&lt;img src="http://l3.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/mSCkTQFkrkzOGPzb3sGLVw--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9ODU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/ap_webfeeds/2c763e62d83a2717190f6a7067003ab4.jpg" width="130" height="86" alt="Greenpeace activists including Executive Director of Greenpeace International, Kumi Naidoo, board energy giant Gazprom's Arctic oil platform Prirazlomnaya off the North-eastern coast of Russia in the Pechora Sea on Friday, Aug. 24, 2012. Greenpeace activists have stormed a floating oil rig in Russia’s Pechora Sea to protest oil drilling in the Arctic, the environmental organization said on Friday. (AP Photo/ Denis Sinyakov, Greenpeace)" align="left" title="Greenpeace activists including Executive Director of Greenpeace International, Kumi Naidoo, board energy giant Gazprom's Arctic oil platform Prirazlomnaya off the North-eastern coast of Russia in the Pechora Sea on Friday, Aug. 24, 2012. Greenpeace activists have stormed a floating oil rig in Russia’s Pechora Sea to protest oil drilling in the Arctic, the environmental organization said on Friday. (AP Photo/ Denis Sinyakov, Greenpeace)" border="0" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;Greenpeace activists stormed a floating Russian oil rig early Friday in the open sea to protest oil drilling in the Arctic, the environmental organization said.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br clear="all"/&gt;</description>
  </story>
  ...
  ...
</news>
 */
?>
```